# Can we have a number as column header in a table?

Tags: sql-server

```
Create table A1
(
    seq_no int, 
    1100 varchar(20)
)
```

With this query, I am getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near 1100

How to overcome this in SQL Server?

Comment: try with this `Create table A1 (seq_no int, [1100] varchar(20))`

Comment: Whilst others have provided answers that are _technically_ correct; you really **must not** create columns that break the naming conventions. [Read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: How strange... link updated. Thanks @marc_s

Comment: @gvee: this one works now - thanks !

Answer (score 7):

You need to put the column name that starts with a number (or that has a space in its name) into **square brackets** - like this:

```
Create table A1
(
    seq_no int, 
    [1100] varchar(20)
)
```

Or just simply avoid such column names - those will continue to cause headache and grief throughout your coding - **avoid** that if ever possible!

Comment: Very valid point on the **avoid**. Avoiding use of any name that needs delimit identifying is *normally* always the best idea. Which means things like Reserved Keywords too (so many SQL Server databases out there with an object called `Order`).

Comment: @marc_s You should see some of the column names in our ETL database. :) [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8dfa9af107c0f4cec088f2a776c234b7)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `[]` if you have a **Space** or **Number as the first character** in a column name.

For example:

- [sample text]
- [1Sample]
- [1100]

Sample code:

```
Create table A1 
(
   seq_no int, 
   [1100] varchar(20) 
)
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=af785d25cae346cbec85ea532fb26033)

Comment: A column *can* have a number in it and doesn't need to be delimit identified. It's only if the *first* character is a number. Something like `tel1` doesn't need to be delimit identified.

Comment: Yes, you are right. i only right answer for whole number or text with space in column nama like ( [100] or [Sample text] )